# How can I catch errors in my firebase function when setting a document fails?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function to create a user document with user data whenever a user registers. How would I return an error when the set() fails? Since this is not an http request (an I don't want to use an http request in this case) I have no response. So how would I catch errors?

```
export const onUserCreated = functions.region('europe-west1').auth.user().onCreate(async user => {

    const privateUserData = {
        phoneNumber: user.phoneNumber
    }

    const publicUserData = {
        name: 'Nameless'
    }

    try
    {
        await firestore.doc('users').collection('private').doc('data').set(privateUserData);
    }catch(error)
    {
        //What do I put here?
    }

    try 
    {
        await firestore.doc('users').collection('public').doc('data').set(publicUserData);
    }catch(error)
    {
        //What do I put here?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "return" an error, since the client doesn't even "know" about this function running, there is nobody to respond to.

You can make a `registration` collection, and in your function make a document there for the current user (using the `uid` as the document id). In that document, you can put any information you'd like your user to know (status, errors, etc).

So your clients would have to add a listener to this document to learn about their registration.

In your particular code, I think the error is in `doc('users')`. I guess you meant `doc('users/'+user.uid)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch -block will receive errors that occur on your set -call:

```js
  try {
    await firestore.doc('users').collection('public').doc('data').set(publicUserData);
  } catch (error) {
    // here you have the error info.  
  }
```

Comment: Yes but how do I pass them to the client? Or the cloud functions console? You would normally do that with the response but since It's not an http request and I don't have response?

Comment: This function is triggered at the backend with no direct relation to front end. So you can not do that directly. One way to handle this is to make your own https function call that will take care of the whole creation of the user at the backend and just not use this kind of triggers.

Comment: In that case, you can return a error response to client.